# SPARQL extension function , where is added to SPARQL grammar?

Tags: sparql, grammar, jena, arq

I want to know when i creating sparql extension functions with apache jena arq, where is it added to the grammar sparql, for the property function and filter function.

Answer (score 2):

The grammar does not change.

A new expression function has a URI and it's invoked as

```
BIND(my:function(?x,?y) AS ?newValue)
```

or in FILTER, in SELECT expressions etc.

Register with `FunctionRegistry.get().put(....)` or use `<java:...>` for auto-loading.

A property function is a property in a triple pattern:

```
?S my:propertyFunction ?O .
```

Register with `PropertyFunctionRegistry.get().put(....)`

Comment: what is about primaryExpression in grammar SPARQL? isn't a extesion function sparql?

Comment: The full quote is "A PrimaryExpression grammar rule can be a call to an extension function named by an IRI." and the naming by IRI is rule:
`[128]   iriOrFunction   ::=   iri ArgList?` which is what I used in the answer.